# Inheritance of a .Net interface in C#: How to access base members

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, outlook-addin

Inheritance of a .Net interface: How to access to base properties

I want to create my own category class inherited from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Category interface but I am trying to access members of the base interface without success.

I tried base.Name and this.Name both give me:

Error   2   'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Using VS 2013, .Net 4.5

Code:

```
using System;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace MyCategory
{
        public class MyCategory : Outlook.Category
    {
        private string colorName; 
        public string ColorName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.colorName;
            }
            set
            {
                //Name is a member of Outlook.Category
                //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.category_members.aspx
                this.colorName = base.Name;
                //
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't inherit properties from an interface...you have to implement the properties that the interface guarantees.

Comment: Instead of inheriting the Category interface (which doesn't make any sense) I'd suggest handling Outlook events and using Outlook form regions. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

So far I see on your code, you didn't implement interface. You're not inheriting from a class but following contract established by `Outlook.Category` interface. There is no "base" members here, you have to add members to your class.

If you put mouse cursor above `Outlook.Category` it should offer to implement it for you.

I recommend you to take a deeper look to [how interfaces work on C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

Comment: Implementing the interface will create this

    public string Name
                {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

But I don't want to re-implement get/set for Name or any other property, I just want to access its value to create new functions.

Comment: Use auto-properties. Use `public string Name { get; set; }`. The same applies for the rest of the properties

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking implementing an interface with object inheritance.  Even though they both use the same syntax, they are very different.

An interface is a contract to allow many different implementations of the same general methods and properties.  It is a guarantee that the class you wrote supports certain actions.  **You have to write the implementations for interfaces**.  This allows others at a higher level to not care about the details of how something gets accomplished, yet it allows them to know it will get accomplished.

Object inheritance allows you to use a parent class's (non-private) stuff.  It's really taking a parent class and adding more features.  In fact, in Java, this is known as "extending" a class.  **Find a class that already implements the interface `Outlook.Category` and inherit from that class** and then call `base.Name()`.  Then you could override or extend any additional behavior that you need.

I'm not familiar with the `Outlook` namespace, but the [`CategoryClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.categoryclass.aspx) seems to be a class that implements your interface.  You could try inheriting from that.

Comment: VS tells that I cannot use CategoryClass and tells me to use the interface.

Comment: Hm that's too bad.  Like I said, you'll have to either implement it yourself, or inherit from something that does implement it.

Answer (score 1):

What is it exactly that you are trying to do? Add a new category in Outlook? In that case, you simply need to access Outlook category storage (either the registry or the default store in the profile).

Take a look at the `IPM.Configuration.CategoryList` hidden message in the Calendar folder - you can see it using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author): go to the Calendar folder, click IMAPIFolder button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the "Associated Contents" tab, find the message with `PR_MESSAGE_CLASS` property = `"IPM.Configuration.CategoryList"`, double click on it. The data will be in the `PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM` property. That hidden message can be accessed using MAPIFolder.GetStorage in the Outlook Object Model.

You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author) to add a new category - see the [RDOCategories](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdocategories.htm) object. Something like the following will do the job (VBA):

```
 set vSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
 vSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
 set vStore = vSession.Stores.DefaultStore
 set vCategories = vStore.Categories
 set vCategory = vCategories.Add("Redemption Category", olCategoryColorPeach)
```

Comment: I am trying to create a addin docked to the interface that allows keyboard input on a textbox to: tag(add category), file(send to folders), modify attributes, etc. I want to inherit the interface in order to get/set categories with extras.

VBA can't create docked components.

Comment: As mentioned by other posters, you cannot derive from a COM interface. Are you thinking about Outlook Task Panes? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx